# Como puedo comparar rango fechas correctamente php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, ajax

Si tengo una fecha en la base de datos `30-06-2017` y 25-07-2017.

```
public static function getByBETWEEN($fecha1,$fecha2){
    $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where date_at > \"$fecha1\" and date_at < \"$fecha2\"";
    $query = Executor::doit($sql);
    return Model::many($query[0],new ReservationData());
}
```

normalmente uso esta sentencia para seleccionar todo esos resultado que estén en ese rango de fecha. pero parece que solo lo selecciona con el día

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que solo lo selecciona con el dia?

Comment: es decir fecha1 = 30-06-2017 y fecha2 = 30-07-2017, dentro de ese rango no funciona en caso contrario si tuviera fecha1 = 26-06-2017 y fecha2 = 28-06-2017 si me obtendría los resultados

Comment: Para que funcione puedes escribirlo así, usando between: `$sql= "select ... from ... where date_at  between '. $fecha1. ' and '.$fecha2.';";` o bien de esta forma: `$sql= "select ... from ... where date_at  >= '. $fecha1. ' and <=  '.$fecha2.';";` funcionará si no se me ha olvidado o escapado algún caracter de más. Aunque yo usaría consultas preparadas por cuestiones de seguridad. El problema es que estás olvidando el signo de igualdad `=` en las comparaciones.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEEN ".$fecha_mas_vieja." AND ".$fecha_mas_reciente;
```

No es tan apropiado utlizar comparadores si tienes una función específica para eso.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

He aquí un ejemplo usando BETWEEN y mejorando la seguridad del código mediante consultas preparadas:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nzgk-rqic)**</kbd>

```
<?php

require "util/public_db_info.php";

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);
$fecha1="1970-01-01";
$fecha2="1999-12-31";

//Uso de consultas preparadas para evitar la Inyección SQL.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM persona WHERE fecha_nacimiento BETWEEN :inicio AND :fin;";    

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":inicio",$fecha1);
$stmt->bindValue(":fin",$fecha2);


$stmt ->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($arrDatos)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "CONSULTA  1:  SE ENCONTRARON  ".count($arrDatos). " REGISTROS\n";
    print_r($arrDatos);    

    $strLista="\n\nLISTA DE DATOS CONSULTA 1:\n";
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
    {
        $strLista.= "id: ".$row["persona_id"]." nombre: ".$row["persona_nom"].
                    " fecha: ".$row["fecha_nacimiento"]."\n";

    }
    echo $strLista;
    echo "</pre>";

}
else
{
    echo "No hay datos";
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM persona;";    

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt ->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($arrDatos)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "\nCONSULTA  2 TODOS LOS DATOS:  SE ENCONTRARON  ".count($arrDatos). " REGISTROS\n";
    print_r($arrDatos);    

    $strLista="LISTA DE DATOS CONSULTA 2:\n";
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
    {
        $strLista.= "id: ".$row["persona_id"]." nombre: ".$row["persona_nom"].
                    " fecha: ".$row["fecha_nacimiento"]."\n";

    }
    echo $strLista;
    echo "</pre>";

}
else
{
    echo "No hay datos";
}

$pdo = null;


?>
```

**Resultado**

```
CONSULTA  1:  SE ENCONTRARON  2 REGISTROS
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [persona_id] => 1
            [persona_nom] => Santiago
            [fecha_nacimiento] => 1974-01-14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [persona_id] => 2
            [persona_nom] => Pedro
            [fecha_nacimiento] => 1972-08-22
        )

)


LISTA DE DATOS CONSULTA 1:
id: 1 nombre: Santiago fecha: 1974-01-14
id: 2 nombre: Pedro fecha: 1972-08-22


CONSULTA  2 TODOS LOS DATOS:  SE ENCONTRARON  3 REGISTROS
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [persona_id] => 1
            [persona_nom] => Santiago
            [fecha_nacimiento] => 1974-01-14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [persona_id] => 2
            [persona_nom] => Pedro
            [fecha_nacimiento] => 1972-08-22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [persona_id] => 3
            [persona_nom] => Juan
            [fecha_nacimiento] => 2002-04-10
        )

)


LISTA DE DATOS CONSULTA 2:
id: 1 nombre: Santiago fecha: 1974-01-14
id: 2 nombre: Pedro fecha: 1972-08-22
id: 3 nombre: Juan fecha: 2002-04-10
```